# dotnet nuke error

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

Hi there im trying to degub a dot net nuke server error and im not sure where to start. I dnt have the code locally else I could debug (no that im familiar the dnn setup). This bug affects making cms updates to the site with the message 'A critical error has occured', I have been unsuccessfully trying to find out the cause and im finally throwing up my hands, I dont even need a fix , I just want to find out what is causing the error so I can provide an estimate for a fix and I can even seem to do that. I have tried looking at the logs but nothing seems to be logged about this error, is there a way to turn off custom error handling so as to get some clues as what the cause of this bug is? any suggestions would be welcome as i am getting desperate here :)

Answer (score 0):

I will try to help you but i will need following information before I start:

1. Is the dnn website loading correctly and then you are getting error on some page or your dnn instance is not accessible?
   in short please provide some more details about how the error comes

Answer (score 0):

Can you try login into system using host account. when you login using host you get a proper stack trace and by that you might get some clue.

Regards